# Solving recurrence equation using RSolve

Tags: equation-solving, recursion, difference-equations

I'm trying to solve the following difference equation:
$$
[k(k-1)+s]\,X_k+k\,X_{k-1}=s\,a^k,\;\;k=1,2,\ldots
$$
assuming that $X_0=1$, and $a,s>0$. The obvious

```
$Assumptions = a > 0 && s > 0;    
RSolve[{(k*(k - 1) + s)*x[k] + k*x[k - 1] == s*a^k, x[0] == 1}, x[k], k]
```

doesn't quite work: it spits out an expression that involves `DifferenceRoot`. Any way to get rid of it?

Incidentally, `RecurrenceTable[{(k*(k - 1) + s)*x[k] + k*x[k - 1] == s*a^k, x[0] == 1}, x, {k,0,5}]` works just fine, but it's still difficult to figure out the pattern.

Comment: But what do you mean it doesn't quite work? `DifferenceRoot` is an exact object in terms of which the solutions to that equation can be solved. Just like with the exact object `Root` which represents the roots of polynomials, it's possible that the solution cannot be expressed in a closed form in terms of more elementary functions. Do you have reason to suspect that it should be?

Comment: @march : yes, the solution is likely to involve special functions, and I was hoping that RSolve would reveal exactly what kind of special functions.